# emulator-arm.exe (Not Responding) Windows 7 x86

Tags: android, windows-7, android-emulator

Currently I am using the following programs for Android development:

- JRE 6.27
- Eclipse Classic Indigo 3.71
- Android SDK revision 12
- Windows 7 Enterprise x86
- Dell Optiplex 780
- Processor Intel Q8400 2.66 GHz
- RAM 4 GB

AVD Settings

- Android 2.3.3: API Level 10
- SD Card: 32 MiB
- Resolution: Built-in (WVGA800)
- Density: 240 (High Density)
- Max VM Heap: 24
- Device RAM size: 512

Everything installs fine, but when I create an AVD and launch it I go straight to the skin with a blank black screen and then it goes to not responding in about 10 seconds. This is lab wide on 17 computers running Windows 7 Enterprise x86. I can take one of the installs and copy it to my work laptop and launch it and all runs fine. I have done the same copy from this install to many other devices and they are fine. Just seem to be having trouble in the lab only.

I check the Application Event log and all I receive is a vague Application Hang error. Have checked numerous threads on here and I am still at a loss. Thanks for any insight into this issue.

Comment: try increasing the ram and decreasing the resolution and what are the system specs ?

Comment: Increasing RAM and decreasing resolution still yields the same results. Also tried updating everything to the new revision 13 and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, but with a configuration of Eclipse 3.6 (Helios) and ADT plug-in v15.0, and Windows XP Pro (I hope you got a solution to your problem, but still, here is my view on it)-
Many people have reported problems occuring with the use of any versions of Eclipse above 3.5 (Galileo) with any version of ADT.
Post switching to Eclipse Galileo, the things seem to be fine, and I've not seen a "not responding" issue with any avd since then.
So, you could probably try down-grading to Eclipse Galileo (the only one with support, since they've stopped support for any versions below 3.5). Hope this helps.